# Flutter How to build a CustomScrollView with a non scrollable part

Tags: flutter

I want to have a view with on top a non scrollable part like an image for example with at the bottom a tab bar that i can scroll to the top to let appear a list of item and be able to scroll inside the list of item.

For that i used a CustomScrollView, with a sliver grid in place of the image for the moment, and a sliver app bar for the tabbar and a sliverFixedExtentList for the list.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new Scaffold(
    body: new CustomScrollView(
      slivers: <Widget>[
        new SliverGrid(
          gridDelegate: new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            childAspectRatio: 0.58,
            crossAxisCount: 1,

          ),
          delegate: new SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return new Container(

                  color: Colors.red,
                  child: new Container(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    child: new Text('IMG HERE'),
                  )
              );
            },
            childCount: 1,

          ),
        ),

        new SliverAppBar(
          title: new Text("title"),
          floating: false,
          pinned: true,
          primary: true,
          actions: <Widget>[
            new IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_upward),
              onPressed: () {
              },
            ),

          ],
          bottom: new TabBar(
            controller: _tabController,
            isScrollable: true,
            tabs: _bars,
          ),
        ),

        new SliverFixedExtentList(
          itemExtent: 100.0,
          delegate: new SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return new Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                color: Colors.lightGreen[100 * (index % 9)],
                child: new Text('list item $index'),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    )
);
```

}

But i have 3 problems :

1. I can't figure out how to make a sliver non scrollable for the slivergrid here.
2. I don't know how to make the appBar be placed exactly at the botom of the screen on launch.
3. I have a problem with the list when the appbar reach the top the list jump some items, it seems it represents the size of the sliverGrid element.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've tried your code and it seems that there are some missing essential parts there. I can't see what's the code behind `_tabController` and `_bars`, so I just made my own `_tabController` and `_bars`. I've run it and this is what I've got so far:

On launch:
[image]

Browsing till the `AppBar` goes to the top.
[image]

So I made some changes in your code for presentation purposes:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController _tabController;
  List<Widget> _bars = [
    Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.image)),
    Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.image)),
  ];
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(length: _bars.length, vsync: this);
    _tabController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        _selectedIndex = _tabController.index;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        body: new CustomScrollView(
      slivers: <Widget>[
        new SliverGrid(
          gridDelegate: new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            childAspectRatio: .69,
            crossAxisCount: 1,
          ),
          delegate: new SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
            (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return SafeArea(
                child: new Container(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  child: new Text('IMG HERE'),
                ),
              );
            },
            childCount: 1,
          ),
        ),
        new SliverAppBar(
          title: new Text("title"),
          floating: false,
          pinned: true,
          primary: true,
          actions: <Widget>[
            new IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_upward),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ],
          bottom: new TabBar(
            controller: _tabController,
            isScrollable: true,
            tabs: _bars,
          ),
        ),
        new SliverFixedExtentList(
          itemExtent: 100.0,
          delegate: new SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
            (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return new Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                color: Colors.lightGreen[100 * (index % 9)],
                child: new Text('list item $index'),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

As you can see, I've played around with the value of `childAspectRatio` so that you can set the AppBar` at the bottom of the screen by default, that's how I understood your question number 2.

For question number 3, it seems that your code is working fine. I am able to properly see the ascending list item from 0 sequenced properly.

And for question number 1, I am quiet confused of how you want it to happen. You don't want the `SliverGrid` to be scrollable but you are expecting the `AppBar` to be on the top of the screen after scrolling. I guess giving more context on this part could give clarity for everyone.